# Dojo DropDownButton, can I differentiate between a click on button vs. down arrow?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I'm using Dojo to create a DropDownButton within a Toolbar.  The Toolbar, and button are created dynamically, like this:

```
this.widget = new Toolbar({ style: "background:black;" }, "toolbar");
this.dropMenu = new DropDownMenu({tooltip : "ToolTip", style: "display: none;"});
this.button = new DropDownButton({dropDown: this.dropMenu});
this.button.set('label', '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+ this.icon + '"/>');
this.widget.addChild(this.button);
```

Note that the above code is dynamically creating an icon as part of the button from a base64 encoded string through setting an img src for the label property of the button.

I want to differentiate between a click on the "label" element for the DropDownButton and a click on the down arrow for the button, but am not sure if this is possible.  Ie, when clicking on the label, I capture the onClick, but don't cause the drop down to be displayed.  However, if the down arrow is clicked on or any other place on the button is clicked, the drop down will be displayed.

One alternate would be to split this into a standard Button, and then a drop down button adjacent to it, but I'm wondering if there is any way to do this from a single standard DropDownButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether or not its the downarrow or buttontext class in the clicked element. To properly hook into the 'flow' of events, you should override the classfunction **_onDropDownMouseDown**

```
var customDropDownButton = declare("customDropDownButton", [ DropDownButton ], {

    toggleDropDown: function() {
        console.log('toggling'); 
        this.inherited(arguments); 
    },
    _onDropDownMouseDown: function(evt) {
        console.log(arguments, evt.srcElement.className);

        if (/dijitButtonText/.test(evt.srcElement.className)) {
            // negate popup functionality 
            console.log('negating');
            return false;
        }
        this.inherited(arguments);
        return true;
    }

});
var b = new customDropDownButton({
    label: "hello!",
    name: "programmatic1",
    dropDown: someMenu
});
```

Alternatively, if you can live with popup showing and then immediately closing again - easy way is:

```
var b = new DropDownButton({
    label: 'hello!',
    name: "programmatic2",
    dropDown: someMenu,

    onClick: function(evt) {
        if(/dijitButtonText/.test(evt.srcElement.className)) {
             // negate popup
             popup.close(this.dropDown);
        }
    }
}, 'button');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this definitely solved the problem for me.